# How to prevent the termination of Anacron jobs after battery mode commences?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron, power-management

I have a backup script which is run daily by Anacron. It can take around 3 hours to complete.

I'm happy for Anacron not to commence the script if the laptop is running on batteries, but once started, I don't want it to be terminated if battery mode commences, since doing so leaves me with an incomplete backup and a false sense of security. The backup uses rsnapshot, which rotates the backups.

How can I disable Anacron's monitoring of power mode for running jobs (or otherwise work around this behaviour)?

I'm running Kubuntu 12.04.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found this blog post titled: [Linux: Anacron tips](http://opensourceresearchtips.blogspot.com/2012/01/linux-anacron-tips.html), which describes how to block anacron from getting killed when the power state is on battery:

*excerpt from blog post*

> IMPORTANT: If your are using anacron on a laptop, anacron will stop
>   (get killed) when running on battery and your scripts will not get
>   executed. This is the default behavior, to save battery.

To change this do the following:

```
sudo gedit /usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/anacron
```

and change to:

```
case $1 in
    false)
 start -q anacron || :
 ;;
    true)
 start -q anacron || :
 ;;
esac
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. Searched for hours and couldn't find that.